# How to fix too many connection request call to ejabber server?

Tags: ejabberd, strophe.js

Facing too many connection calls while trying to connect my react application with Ejabberd server. I am using strophe library for the connection between React end to Ejabberd server

Due to this problem, Ejabber server blocked some amount of time and unblocked after some time.

*Error message in Ejabber while too many connections* ***"Too many requests from the same IP"***

Comment: Can you try 'max_user_sessions: infinity' in the settings and try?